# Firefox refresh button not working

Tags: refresh, firefox3.6

Anyone else ever have the Firefox toolbar "refresh" button not work for a particular page? Works everywhere else. Firefox 3.6.15. Any clues?

EDIT: For what it's worth, I later set network.http.use-cache false, and the problem went away. No idea whether that was much more than coincidence, though.

Comment: Just to clarify, I can get the effect of a refresh by pressing "enter" in the URL box, just the button seems not to be working.

Comment: Weird. Intermittent. I've seen it again, but not consistently.

Comment: Pressing Ctrl+R, F5 or clicking the refresh button is not doing the same thing as pressing enter in the navigation bar, but Ctrl+F5 works for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a lot of detail to go on in your question, but what will often happen is that firefox will cache certain elements of the page and not actually re-fetch them from the server.  Try using the TamperData Add-On for firefox to see exactly what data is being transferred from the web server.

You can also just try a Ctrl-F5 to do a force page reload.

Comment: Happens to be a page from my own localhost, and I haven't messed with anything unusual lately.

Comment: Ctrl-F5 fails exactly like the button. Only workaround I've found is ENTER on the URL line.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't say that I have had that problem, most "weird" behaviors I've run into were due to extensions. You might try disabling some of the more intrusive ones. Greasemonkey perhaps?

Comment: No Greasemonkey, and haven't added anything lately. And it's no problem on any other page.